# Using custom field (i.e: location) instead of coordinate in GeoFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

My database contains `geopoint` in a field named `location` but to use [`geofirestore`](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js#geofirestore) a field needs to have valid `geopoint` data named as `coordinate`.

But the problem is the database contains large amount of data & multiple application is consuming them, so its not a good idea to change the filed name.
[image]

Another field `l` contains `latitude` and `longitude` as of type `number`.

Any idea to get a working solution (if possible)? Suggestions/answers are appreciated :)
thinking about modifying the library..not sure what to do..

Just to mention: I've tested with a dummy database structured this & working correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The location being in `coordinates` is only necessary for add/set functions, so geofirestore knows what to use as the geopoint for the geohash. If you dont want to use the `coordinates` field you can pass in a string as a custom field [https://geofirestore.com/classes/*geocollectionreference*.geocollectionreference.html#add](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geocollectionreference_.geocollectionreference.html#add) (this is different with set, please check the docs)

You also don't *need* to have the data in the `d` field and keep it top level with the `l`, and `g`. However geofirestore will not perform compound queries (as it queries only in the `d` field), as well as when you update the data it will push the updates into the `d` area. So maybe only use geofirestore for the geoquery, and do your updates with firestore.